# Streaming my own music

Tags: music, cloud, stream

I'm a music producer who constantly renders new music to take on the road and listen.  Currently I use iTunes Cloud, which allows me to upload my music and stream from all ios devices.  Is this somehow possible with Ubuntu One streaming?  I did notice that it shows up in the files app, but that requires downloading to play.

Comment: Not definitive b/c I haven't done it, but I heard streaming from U1 is possible for desktops and Android, but that OSX (and possibly iOS) don't have proper clients.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One has a Music streaming app for iPhone - see https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/iphone/

As an alternative, if you can set up your own server you can use Subsonic (http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) to organise your music and stream it to any web browser. Their are also streaming apps for iOS and Android.